# Compiler throw an error while storing derived class address to base class address

Tags: c++, inheritance

**Working Case**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;

class A{
    public:
    A(){
        cout << "A" << endl;
    }
    
    virtual void foo()
    {
        cout << "A' foo" << endl;
    }
};

class B{
    public:
    B(){
        cout << "B" << endl;
    }
    
    virtual void foo()
    {
        cout << "B' foo" << endl;
    }
};

class C{
    public:
    C(){
        cout << "C" << endl;
    }
    
    virtual void foo()
    {
        cout << "C' foo" << endl;
    }
};

class D : public B,A,C{
    public:
    D(){
        cout << "D" << endl;
    }
    
    void foo()
    {
        cout << "D' foo" << endl;
        A::foo();
    }
};

int main()
{
    class B*ptr = new D;
    return 0;
}
```

**Error case**
A is base class of class D , but why compiler dont allow to store the derived class address to base class?

```
int main()
{
    class A*ptr = new D;
    return 0;
}
```

> output: error: ‘A’ is an inaccessible base of ‘D’

**Always Working Case:**
Derived each class with specific access specifier.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;

class A{
    public:
    A(){
        cout << "A" << endl;
    }
    
    virtual void foo()
    {
        cout << "A' foo" << endl;
    }
};

class B{
    public:
    B(){
        cout << "B" << endl;
    }
    
    virtual void foo()
    {
        cout << "B' foo" << endl;
    }
};

class C{
    public:
    C(){
        cout << "C" << endl;
    }
    
    virtual void foo()
    {
        cout << "C' foo" << endl;
    }
};

class D : public B, public A, public C{
    public:
    D(){
        cout << "D" << endl;
    }
    
    void foo()
    {
        cout << "D' foo" << endl;
        A::foo();
    }
};

int main()
{
    class A*ptr = new D;
    return 0;
}
```

Can somebody explain to me how access specifiers work in this situation, given that derived classes in both cases inherit from base classes?

Comment: What's there to explain? The ability to convert `D *` to `A *` requires the `A` to be the accessible base of `A` (either public, or the conversion has to be inside the class).

Comment: for multiple inheritance, able to store Derived class address to base class pointer when derived class is inherited by using access specifier for each class For example 
class D : public A, public B, public C{
}

in this case class B* ptr = new D; //works fine

class D : public A, B, C{
}

in this case class B* ptr = new D; //compiler throw an error

Comment: Yes, because `public A, B, C` is the same thing as `public A, private B, private C`.

Comment: Compilers don't *throw errors*, this usage has to stop. Throw has a very specific meaning in C++ and it has nothing to do with compiler errors.

Answer (score 3):

> ```
> class D : public B,A,C
> ```

Only `B` is a public base class of `D`.  We can't access `A` because it is a *private* base class.

Perhaps you intended:

```
class D : public B, public A, public C
```

Comment: Yes, OP shows `class D : public B, public A, public C` further below in the question.

Comment: Does this mean that base class pointers cannot hold the address of derived class addresses if base class inherits as a private property to derived class?

Comment: It is not an issue of holding any address. It is the fact that you have a derived class to start with. In order to store a pointer to a base class, when you have a pointer to a derived class, the base class must be accessible, just like any method of the base class. If the base class is private you cannot access it.

Answer (score 1):

```
class D : public B, A, C
```

The public access specifier here only applies to `B`. It doesn't apply to `A` nor `C`.

In other words, no access specifier has been specified for `A` and `C` so by default, their inheritance type  will be 'private'. That is why you see the error:

> output: error: ‘A’ is an inaccessible base of ‘D’

If you want `public` to apply to `A` and `C`, use:

```
class D : public B, public A, public C
```